# Como dar zoom em uma imagem com opencv e C++?

Tags: c++, imagem, opencv

tenho que programar um algoritmo para dar zoom em uma imagem sem usar as ferramentas do opencv, mas não estou conseguindo fazer. Como dar zoom em uma imagem usando laços for?

```
Mat img = imread("copo.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
Mat img2 = Mat::zeros(img.size(), CV_8UC3);
int wid = img.size().width;
int hei = img.size().height;
for(int i = 0;i < wid;i++){
    for(int j = 0;j < hei;j++){
        for(int k = 0;k < 100;k++){
            for(int h = 0;h < 100;h++){
                img2.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = img.at<Vec3b>(k, h);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Verifique esse exemplo no github, veja se consegue adaptá-lo para seu caso: https://github.com/brutalchrist/ejemplosOpencv/blob/master/zoom.cpp

Comment: Vc diz que é "sem usar OpenCV", mas sua pergunta tem ele na tag, no título e até mesmo no código. Se você já usa o OpenCV, por que reinventar a roda?

Comment: Bom, não fui muito claro. O OpenCV é necessário para carregar a imagem na matriz além de outras ferramentas. O OpenCV possui várias ferramentas que me permitiriam fazer o zoom com facilidade, mas o desafio do exercício é fazer o zoom sem utilizar essas ferramentas, apenas o recurso de matrizes do OpenCV. E eu estou tendo dificuldades com isso. Até então a roda não precisa ser reinventada só porque eu não uso todas as ferramentas.